# Facebook app: within Canvas, Facebook treats GETs as POSTs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

In my Rails FB app, when running in the canvas, if I go to "/users", instead of `GET`ting the index page, it `POST`s and creates a new user.

That only happens when I try to access the URL directly. When I use the "List of users" link on the app, it works as expected.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's just how FB does it. They post data with each query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sends everything as POST which brakes RESTful routes. There is a way to fix it though. If incoming POST request contains `signed_request` parameter you can assume it was converted from GET to POST by Facebook.

[Rack::Facebook::MethodFix](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/rack-facebook-methodfix) middleware fixes the problem automagically. You can use it with something like:

```
# Basic usage
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix

# Also validate signed_request
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix, :secret_id => "c561df165eacdd6e32672c9eaee10318"

# Do not apply request method fix to admin urls.
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix, :exclude => proc { |env| env["PATH_INFO"].match(/^\/admin/) }
```

or if you are using Rails then

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix
```

Comment: _“you can assume it was converted from GET to POST by Facebook.”_ – there is no “conversion” happening. Facebook loads the initial URL for a page tab app into the iframe by POSTing the contents of a form – this has been this way from the very beginning, and if an app can’t handle that, it’s the app’s fault alone.

Comment: "From the very beginning" being March 12th 2011 when change happened. 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/

Comment: OK, wasn’t aware of that. Still, when this question was asked, it was already in place.